# How to deploy application in eclipse to azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to deploy a java EE application in eclipse to azure. After giving the publish profile, i was asked to enter the subscription ID and pfx file password. I have got the subscription ID from azure portal but how to get the pfx file password? Actually what is a pfx file and how to get/create it?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't recycle an existing one, as that invalidates the existing answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

A PFX file is just a certificate file type.  I would recommend that you delete the subscription(s) you have setup in Eclipse and re-import the one you want to use.  The instructions for doing this can be [found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh690944.aspx) (see underneath the "To deploy your application to Azure" header near the bottom). You shouldn't need to enter a password.